# Can't spawn daemon server from jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, server, environment-variables, daemon, caddy

I'm trying to spawn a webserver from a Jenkins build job, and although the job succeeds, I'm running into the issue that Jenkins automatically kills background jobs when the job exits.

```
+ caddy -port 26748 &
Activating privacy features... done.
:26748
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I read the Jenkins documentation about [spawning processes from build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build), and also about the [ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller), which tell me that I should be able to achieve this by daemonizing the process and setting the `BUILD_ID` environment variable to something else, so I tried this:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe daemon --env="BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" --name="my-process" -- caddy -root `pwd` -port 26748
```

However, although I no longer get the `Process leaked file descriptors` message, this still seems to be killing the process on exit. Although I tried running the exact same command as the Jenkins user directly on the box and it works fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? How can I get this process to live on after the job has exited?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the `BUILD_ID` needs to be set specifically for the `daemon` process, rather than it's child process. For some reason, `BUILD_ID=dontkillme daemon` was not doing this effectively.

I solved this by running the `daemon` command within a `bash` session with the new `BUILD_ID` passed through to the `bash` session:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe bash -c "daemon --name="my-process" --command 'caddy -root `pwd` -port 26748'"
```

This now successfully leaves my daemon process running.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can do alternatively but it is a bit more cumbersome however effective.

What you can do is to execute a bash script through a ssh connection and send it to the background while saving the pid of the process somewhere so you can make checks further.

The format of the command would be:

```
ssh -n _hostname_ "_commands_ & echo \$! > \"_path_to_pid_file_\"" &
```

Example with a never-ending program:

```
ssh -n mycomputer.mydomain.com "tail -f /var/log/my.log & echo \$! > \"$WORKSPACE/pid\"" &
```

This example will spawn the tail process listening forever for new changes in the /var/log/my.log file and store its pid in the $WORKSPACE/pid file.

When executed from a Jenkins job the ssh process will be killed by Jenkins once the job finishes while the commands sent to the background will remain in execution in the specified host.

I do this often for checking and spawning processes whose source code is under source control (usually git).

Hope this helps!